VIPS: How to convert ActiveStorage attachment to webp or avif
I would like to resize and transform jpg image to webp and avif
I tried several solution, but always get a jpg image.
<%= image_tag @attachment.variant(resize_and_pad: [300, 300, background: [255]]) %>

# JPEG
<%= image_tag @attachment.variant(saver: { strip: true, quality: 80, interlace: true }) %>

# PNG
<%= image_tag @attachment.variant(saver: { strip: true, compression: 9 }).processed %>

# WEBP
<%= image_tag @attachment.variant(resize_and_pad: [300, 300, background: [255]], saver: { strip: true, quality: 75, lossless: false, alpha_q: 85, reduction_effort: 6, smart_subsample: true }).processed %>

# GIF
<%= image_tag @attachment.variant(saver: { optimize_gif_frames: true, optimize_gif_transparency: true }).processed %>

# AVIF
<%= image_tag @attachment.variant(format: :avif, saver: { quality: 75, lossless: false }).processed %>
<%= image_tag @attachment.variant(saver: { format: :avif, quality: 75, lossless: false }).processed  %>


#jpg
<%= image_tag @attachment.variant(format: :jpg, saver: { strip: true, quality: 80 }).processed %>


As mentioned in the Documentation the operations are as specified by ImageProcessing::Vips it appears you are looking for the convert option: "Specifies the output format." or possibly apply

...It is also worth noting the following regarding saver: *"Any provided options that are not defined for a specific saver will be ignored.
By default, libvips will select the appropriate saver based on the file extension of the destination path. If libvips fails to understand the file extension, you can force a specific saver"*. Example given is saver: :tiff, rather than saver: {format: :tiff}
